# How to convert signature pad signature into pdf file by ajax, javascript and php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have integrated signature pad in HTML, CSS and JavaScript from [this site](https://codepen.io/kunukn/pen/kkbNvx) and have activated save button to save signature in `.png` file but now I need to change from `.png` to `.pdf` file.

How can I achieve this?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rzKYXV0vdQk-qqX7PuWR0w0QeikWwE59) are my google drive code files

Comment: you can use Dompdf PHP library to convert HTML to PDF. like:  


    $html = "<img src='PATH TO PNG'>";
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();

Comment: sure. check this: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: hello rajinder i don't want the dompdf. I just want to save my signature in pdf this thing uses composer and i don't want composer in it. I just want to make it simple.

Comment: there is no option for the chat. don't expect the whole code from the community. you have to do some efforts. PHP can't convert the image file into PDF without any library. you have to use one of the library